# How to test php Contact Form

Tags: php, html, css, contacts

I created a contact form in PHP however, I am trying to test it by filling it out to make sure it works and is formatted correctly in my inbox. How would I go about testing it? I tried xampp but I have been getting many errors. Is there any other ways to test it?

Comment: You need to post the errors you are getting and we can help you debug them. Without more context though it is going to be hard to give any help. The errors you might be experiencing very well could be the result of something being wrong with your code that will go wrong no matter where you try to test this.

Comment: Always make sure to post a [reprex], so we don't have to guess what might be wrong...

Comment: "formatted correctly in my inbox" is subjective, and although you could use mail interceptors or something similar, the easiest is to probably just send the email and look at it.